# Defining numerated lists without using enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate

I want to create a list-environment in Latex that is aligned at the left side of the page. For normal bullet lists, I already have a solution:

```
\newenvironment{FHitemize}{\begin{list}{$\bullet$} {\leftmargin1.5em \labelsep1em
\rightmargin0cm \parsep0.5ex plus0.2ex minus0.1ex\itemsep0ex plus0.2ex}}{\end{list}}
```

This leads to the following result:

[image]

Now, I want the same, but with an enumerated list.
I already tried the following, however, it does not count up the items.

```
\newenvironment{FHenumerate}{\begin{list}{$\arabic*$} {\leftmargin1.5em \labelsep1em
\rightmargin0cm \parsep0.5ex plus0.2ex minus0.1ex \itemsep0ex plus0.2ex}}{\end{list}}
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work? I most likely need to change the part after `\begin{list}{$XXXXXXXX$}`, however I did not find a way to do so.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Load the `enumitem` package and use `\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=*}`  in the preamble.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you, this helped me. Should I delete this question?

Comment: I don't think so. It might help some people who try to have a custom layout of list environment, but are not aware of the enumitem package.